# How to access a class with specific parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project with `class Matrix < ActiveRecord::Base`, and I'm hitting situations where `Matrix.where` is crashing because it's trying to access the `Matrix < Enumerable` class from ruby.

Is there a way to specify which `Matrix` I want, like `ActiveRecord::Base::Matrix`?

I know I could rename the model, but it would be a pain (old spaghetti project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename it or be forever battling Ruby core. You can't get around this. Rails chose to put model names in the root namespace as it's very convenient, but leads to problems when that conflicts with either Rails or Ruby.

Solutions:

- Try and force-load your model before the Ruby `Matrix` has a chance to usurp it

  - This may have unintended consequences (like a crash) should `require 'matrix'` show up somewhere
  - This could also mess up gems that expect `Matrix` to be the Ruby thing and not your random model
- Move it into a namespace like `MyProject::Matrix`
- Rename it to something dumb like `MMatrix` as a reminder that this name was a bad idea from the outset

The good news is that if this is a fairly unique string, then a global replace of `Matrix` to the alternate name is probably not going to be that bad.